# java: what does it mean it by : obtainedMarks = se.nextInt();

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java programming and I want to know : What does it mean  by or it's function:
 obtainedMarks = se.nextInt();
in this code :

```
package ifstatment;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ifstatment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int obtainedMarks ;
    int passingMarks;
    String  grade;
    Scanner se = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your scoor");
    passingMarks = 40 ;
    obtainedMarks = se.nextInt();
    if (obtainedMarks >= passingMarks ){
        if (obtainedMarks > 90)
            grade = "A";
        else if (obtainedMarks > 75)
            grade = "B";
                    else if (obtainedMarks > 65)
             grade =  "C";
        else
            grade ="D";
            System.out.println("You passed the exam and your grade is"+ grade);

    } else {
        grade = "F";
        System.out.println("You failed in thee exam and your grade is " + grade);
    }
    } 
}
```

Comment: It simply reads the next integer from `System.in`, i.e. the console input and saves it to `obtainedMarks` (which is by the way not a good name, `obtainedMark` would make more sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading an int from the console and saves it to the `obtainedMarks` variable.

You can read more about Scanner [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
se.nextInt()
```

reads the next `int` value from the input stream (`System.in` in your case) and returns that value.

```
obtainedMarks = se.nextInt()
```

"takes" that value and assigns it to the variable `obtainedMarks`.

Answer (score 0):

se.nextInt()
This mean that you will input an integer from console and assign it to var **obtainedMarks**

Please access this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for more information.